# Display topic name on topic detail (Napili)

Tags: napili, topics

I have featured topics on my FAQs page that I use as a "category" for all the articles I store. Clicking a featured article will load the Topic Detail page where all articles under that topic are listed. However, I wanted to show a title above all this articles, basically showing that featured topic that was clicked.

I can get the ID of the topic written in the url using {! topicId } but what I want is the actual topic

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found an answer by trial and error.

On the topic detail page, you can click on the headline and have it configured. For the page type, it should be 'topic' and for the Unique ID, it should be {!urlName}